# VBA Macro extremely slow: 15 min runtime

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code, it takes some values from a file, looks them up in another file and pastes a value in the row where it fins those values. My file tg has 126 lines and 135 columns. My file gar_nv has 2553 lines and 67 columns. My variable nbrLines is equal to 2553.
It takes 15 min to finish running. I'm wondering which part is making it so slow ? Or is it because of how big my sheets are. Thanks

```
Sub Remb()
Call Workbook_open

Dim acte, acte_next, Remb, Col, Col_next, produit As Variant
Dim colonne, ligne, Line, r, c As Long

With tg

   For colonne = col_dep To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
    
        For ligne = ligne_dep To nbrLines
        
            acte = tg.Range(ColName(colonne) & ligne)
            r = ligne
            c = Columns(ColName(colonne)).Column
            MsgBox (acte)
                
            
            If Not IsEmpty(acte) Then
                Remb = .Cells(r, c).Offset(0, -1).Value 
                Col = .Cells(r, c).Offset(0, 1).Value 
                produit = .Cells(6, c).Value 
                
                acte_next = .Cells(r, c).Offset(1, 0).Value
                Col_next = .Cells(r, c).Offset(1, 1).Value
                
        
                
                For Line = 1 To gar_nv.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                
                    If gar_nv.Range("GCGAR6").Rows(Line).Value Like produit Then
                        If gar_nv.Range("GCBARB").Rows(Line).Value Like acte Then
                            
                           gar_nv.Range(Col).Rows(Line).Value = Remb
                           
                        End If
                    End If
                Next Line
            End If
        Next ligne
    Next colonne
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: it is the triple nested loops, you have a little shy of 1 billion iterations.

Comment: There is no need to use `Offset` when using the `Cells` object, e.g. `Remb = .Cells(r,c-1).Value2`. Also, in your declaration, the variables `colonne, ligne, Line, r` are _all_ of type `Variant`, which is less efficient than type `Long`

Comment: Also, consider whether you can use `AutoFilter` in your code - by filtering for specific conditions you will only have to iterate through `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` _and_ be able to avoid the test on those cells, rather than iterating over 100% of cells and testing _each_ and _every_ value. [Efficient Uses of Excel Loops](https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/VBALoops.htm)

Comment: This won't make any speed difference, but can't `c = Columns(ColName(colonne)).Column` be condensed down to `c = colonne`, or just remove one of those altogether and just use the other?

Comment: does `acte` need to be of `Variant` type? In this code it gets set as a range, but then tested as a value - unless used as a range elsewhere in code not posted here, `Long` or `String` would be better.

Comment: @SpencerBarnes you're right, thanks. I made the modifications but it doesn't make it any faster.

Comment: As Per Warcupine's comment, it's the loops that will be taking up the time - try to think of ways to shorten these (e.g. if there's only one cell per `produit` and `acte` that needs `.value = remb`, then once that is found add an `exit for` to save having to check the rest of the range).